# как добавить картинку внутри текста при наведении hover

Tags: html, css, hover

не понимаю как сделать так чтобы при наведении на текст hover снизу текста появлялась картинка, помогите

Comment: Не помешает добавить чуть-чуть кода, который у вас есть. Чтобы мы понимали - о чём речь

Answer (score 1):

```css
    .foo:hover .hidden-img{
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .hidden-img{
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
     <div class='foo'>
        <p>Текст</p>
        <img class="hidden-img" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/b9/59/f1/b959f1670d2631589643575de5a782b7.jpg" alt="Тест">
      </div>
```

Помещаем картинку и текст внутрь обёртки и на неё вешаем `hover`
P.S. Изначально теги div и p - блочные и занимают всю ширину. Поэтому по наведении на строку, где они содержатся, hover будет срабатывать. Если это не нужно - .foo и p нужно сделать `display: inline-block`

Comment: А вы точно уверены, что когда я навожу курсор справа от текста (Не на текст), изображение должно появляется?

Comment: Это происходит из-за того, что p изначально display:block и занимает всю строку. Чтобы такого не было - можно добавить к p display: inline-block или другой

Comment: Я знаю почему это происходит, другое дело что по вопросу, ваш ответ не совсем корректный, нужно сделать так, чтобы (внимание цитата) "при наведении на текст снизу текста появлялась картинка", а у вас получается при наведении на блок `.foo`.

Comment: Спасибо, поправил

Answer (score 0):

А я бы сделал так:

```css
.img-onhover img {
  display: none;
}

.img-onhover .img-onhover-text {
  display: inline-block;
}

.img-onhover .img-onhover-text:hover + img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-onhover">
  <p class="img-onhover-text">Hover on Me!</p>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmRDh.png">
</div>
```